# Trying to parse 'JSON' in TypeScript: but is this JSON?

Tags: json, typescript

First, I am duly embarrassed.  I *should* know this.

I'm learning TypeScript and when I try to parse the data below (which I was given, told it was JSON) using `JSON.parse()` TypeScript complains that the data is not a string.  I get that -- it isn't.  If I wrap the entire thing in quotes, however, It doesn't work either.

I find myself lost and rather embarrassed as I'm a mid-level programmer.  What am I missing here?

For what it's worth, I'm importing a large data array (the array is huge, I've only given the first two entries below) in my React app using

```
import data from './data/data.json'
```

and then attempting to convert it to a JS array using

```
const parsedArray:Array<any> = JSON.parse(data).
```

But of course, as per above, it fails.

I *want* to end up with a JS data structure where the numbers are numbers again, not strings.

The data is as follows:

```
 [{"_id":"5bb238cbf839d08d65633450","index":0,"guid":"390322bb-3e93-4196-853a-e6e7a6f455bb","isActive":true,"balance":"$2,193.03","picture":"http://placehold.it/32x32","age":62,"eyeColor":"brown","name":"Holder Joyce","gender":"male","company":"RAMEON","email":"holderjoyce@rameon.com","phone":"+1 (942) 548-3425","address":"168 Ovington Court, Eagleville, Oregon, 1098","about":"Voluptate eiusmod exercitation ad aliqua ullamco ex officia. Fugiat deserunt anim commodo anim reprehenderit cillum cupidatat magna anim. Do in sint elit deserunt sint amet veniam culpa et veniam.\r\n","registered":"2017-09-21T02:55:55 -02:00","latitude":53.144539,"longitude":111.973422,"favorites":{"cavatappi":3.1604049168546533,"fusilli":47.41214262743145,"spaghetti":36.351431171952584,"tagliatelle ":16.540786406823592,"farfalle":29.91825944401951}},{"_id":"5bb238cbf839d08d65633450","index":0,"guid":"390322bb-3e93-4196-853a-e6e7a6f455bb","isActive":true,"balance":"$2,193.03","picture":"http://placehold.it/32x32","age":62,"eyeColor":"brown","name":"Holder Joyce","gender":"male","company":"RAMEON","email":"holderjoyce@rameon.com","phone":"+1 (942) 548-3425","address":"168 Ovington Court, Eagleville, Oregon, 1098","about":"Voluptate eiusmod exercitation ad aliqua ullamco ex officia. Fugiat deserunt anim commodo anim reprehenderit cillum cupidatat magna anim. Do in sint elit deserunt sint amet veniam culpa et veniam.\r\n","registered":"2017-09-21T02:55:55 -02:00","latitude":53.144539,"longitude":111.973422,"favorites":{"cavatappi":3.1604049168546533,"fusilli":47.41214262743145,"spaghetti":36.351431171952584,"tagliatelle ":16.540786406823592,"farfalle":29.91825944401951}}]
```

Any help as to what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated. I've spent 45 minutes trying to figure this out and I'm missing something crucial.  As I said, I was given the file of data, with the name `data.json`,  so I thought, naively, that I could just read it in and parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `import` a file, or use `require()` typescript / node.js will parse the file for you and return the result.

So instead of:

```
const parsedArray:Array<any> = JSON.parse(data).
```

You use:

```
const parsedArray:Array<any> = data;
```

Comment: Thanks, perfect!  But just for my understanding, what _is_ in the original file then?  It's not a JSON string, right?  Is it just an array of JS objects, then?  If it's JS, then why is it called JSON?

Comment: Any file is really just a 'string'. There's no fundamental difference between an array of objects, or a JSON string if you just look at a file. JSON was originally invented to be a subset of Javascript. The reason importing JSON files works is simply because that's how the typescript node.js engineers designed it though.